# How to improve SQL query w/ JOINs?

Tags: mysql, sql, grails

I'm using MySQL 5.5. I have these 3 tables: News, NewsSubTopic, SubTopic. I wonder why this query is slow:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT COUNT(news0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
FROM
  news news0_
INNER JOIN
  news_sub_topic subtopics1_ 
ON
  news0_.id = subtopics1_.news_sub_topics_id
INNER JOIN
  sub_topic subtopic2_ 
ON
  subtopics1_.sub_topic_id = subtopic2_.id 
WHERE
  (subtopic2_.id IN (55 , 134 , 135 , 52 , 53 , 32 , 54))
  AND news0_.type = 'api';
```

I already placed index key in news.type. Is it possible to add keys in NewsSubTopic?

Here are some stats: News table has **1,088,126** entries, NewsSubTopic has **823,247** entries, and SubTopic has **168**.

Note that that query is generated by a Grails (or Hibernate). Can you please explain on how to debug the query and understand why it is slow (3-5 seconds)? And is there any other way to improve it (I can provide other info that you need).

Comment: You should check out the [Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) syntax.

Comment: yes, i tried that too. but i'm not yet that familiar on how to interpret the result. care to share a few tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `DISTINCT`, arguments to `COUNT` or a reference to `sub_topic`:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    news_sub_topic ns
JOIN    news n
ON      n.id = ns.news_sub_topics_id
WHERE   ns.sub_topic_id IN (55 , 134 , 135 , 52 , 53 , 32 , 54)
        AND n.type = 'api'
```

Create a composite index on `news_sub_topic (sub_topic_id, news_sub_topics_id)`

Note that `DISTINCT COUNT(…)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT …)` are the different things. If you need the latter, use this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT n.id)
FROM    news_sub_topic ns
JOIN    news n
ON      n.id = ns.news_sub_topics_id
WHERE   ns.sub_topic_id IN (55 , 134 , 135 , 52 , 53 , 32 , 54)
        AND n.type = 'api'
```

Could you please explain what do you want to do with your query?

Comment: note that the SQL statement i gave was from slow_query.log. after reviewing the Grails code (which i didn't code), it simply wants to count all items in News table where type = 'api' and belongs to the specified SubTopics. and i agree that DISTINCT is not necessary. btw, thanks for the improve query! from 3s it went down to 90ms. make sense! totally missed that approach. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Despite what has already been said, your query might be not [Sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).
You will need to create indexes for your join conditions to make you query as less sensitive to the news_sub_topics_id as possible.

Make sure to use very selective indexes too (order your index fields by selectivity (VerySelective, LessSelective, ...).

Comment: `MySQL` is not capable of doing hash joins.

Comment: so it is possible to create an index to a FK? how to do that?

Comment: You can index whatever you want per table. See the documentation to learn how to create indexes http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: but shouldn't primary key and foreign keys already indexed by default?

Comment: Yes, they are indexed since a PK, FK are indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are doing this:

```
        ...
        ON
        news0_.id = subtopics1_.news_sub_topics_id
```

Wouldn't NEWS.id be its PK and wouldn't there be another column like NEWS.topicid that you'd want to use when joining to topics?

You could try to cull the subtopics  first:

```
            select distinct newssubtopicid from newssubtopic as NS
            inner join subtopic ST on NS.subtopicid = ST.id
            and ST.id in (55 , 134 , 135 , 52 , 53 , 32 , 54)
```

ST.id is its PK, no? There should be an index on NS.subtopicid.  How long does the above query take?

At that point you know which news subtopics you need for pulling the relevant news items:

```
          select count(NEWS.id) from NEWS
          inner join 
          (
            select distinct newssubtopicid from newssubtopic as NS
            inner join subtopic ST on NS.subtopicid = ST.id
            and ST.id in (55 , 134 , 135 , 52 , 53 , 32 , 54)
          ) as T
          on NEWS.topicid = T.newssubtopicid
```

Comment: note that NewsSubTopic is the many-many relationship table of News and SubTopic that's why the news0_.id = subtopics1_.news_sub_topics_id is necessary. but adding a field in News could be a good idea, i'll think about that. thanks!